# Properly destroying the VBE

Tags: c#, .net, rubberduck, com

The [disposable wrappers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/142916/23788) worked exactly as intended... and that turned out being a huge mistake:

[image: Error: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannnot be used]

That's because the .net runtime creates a *Runtime Callable Wrapper* per-type, not per-instance*; it took a number of refactorings and adjustments just to be able to get the project to build and run, and then over 900 tests were broken and my life was a nightmare.

Then I had an idea: since .net wouldn't let me destroy objects that were otherwise ready to be collected, what if I ditched `IDisposable` and moved on to a hierarchical teardown strategy?

Enter `ISafeComWrapper`:

```
namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers
{
    public interface ISafeComWrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Releases all COM objects.
        /// </summary>
        void Release();
    }
}
```

In the `Extension` class (which you may recall seeing [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/141956/23788)), we `Release` the entire VBE object graph, like this:

> ```
> private void ShutdownAddIn()
> {
>     if (_app != null)
>     {
>         _app.Shutdown();
>         _app = null;
>     }
>
>     if (_kernel != null)
>     {
>         _kernel.Dispose();
>         _kernel = null;
>     }
>
>     _ide.Release();
>     _isInitialized = false;
> }
> ```

So here's the `SafeComWrapper<T>` base class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers
{
    public abstract class SafeComWrapper<T> : ISafeComWrapper, IEquatable<SafeComWrapper<T>> 
        where T : class 
    {
        protected SafeComWrapper(T comObject)
        {
            _comObject = comObject;
        }

        public abstract void Release();

        private readonly T _comObject;
        public T ComObject { get { return _comObject; } }
        public bool IsWrappingNullReference { get { return _comObject == null; } }

        protected TResult InvokeResult<TResult>(Func<TResult> member)
        {
            try
            {
                return member.Invoke();
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);                
            }
        }

        protected void Invoke(Action member)
        {
            try
            {
                member.Invoke();
            }
            catch (COMException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exception)
            {
                throw new WrapperMethodException(exception);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <c>true</c> when wrapping a <c>null</c> reference and <see cref="other"/> is either <c>null</c> or wrapping a <c>null</c> reference.
        /// </summary>
        protected bool IsEqualIfNull(SafeComWrapper<T> other)
        {
            return (other == null || other.IsWrappingNullReference) && IsWrappingNullReference;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as SafeComWrapper<T>);
        }

        public abstract bool Equals(SafeComWrapper<T> other);
        public abstract override int GetHashCode();

        public static bool operator ==(SafeComWrapper<T> a, SafeComWrapper<T> b)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return !ReferenceEquals(a, null) && a.Equals(b);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(SafeComWrapper<T> a, SafeComWrapper<T> b)
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }

        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "RedundantCast")]
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "ForCanBeConvertedToForeach")]
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "LoopCanBeConvertedToQuery")]
        protected int ComputeHashCode(params object[] values) // incurs boxing penalty for value types
        {
            unchecked
            {
                const int initial = (int)2166136261;
                const int multiplier = (int)16777619;
                var hash = initial;
                for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    hash = hash * multiplier + values[i].GetHashCode();
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

The derived types all implement `IEquatable<WhateverTheTypeIs>` on top of having to override `GetHashCode`, the base `Equals<SafeComWrapper<T>>` method and the `Release` method - here's the `AddIn` wrapper implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers.VBA
{
    public class AddIn : SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.AddIn>, IEquatable<AddIn>
    {
        public AddIn(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.AddIn comObject) 
            : base(comObject)
        {
        }

        public string ProgId
        {
            get
            {
                return IsWrappingNullReference ? null : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.ProgId);
            }
        }

        public string Guid
        {
            get { return IsWrappingNullReference ? null : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Guid); }
        }

        public VBE VBE
        {
            get { return new VBE(InvokeResult(() => IsWrappingNullReference ? null : ComObject.VBE)); }
        }

        public AddIns Collection
        {
            get { return new AddIns(InvokeResult(() => IsWrappingNullReference ? null : ComObject.Collection)); }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return IsWrappingNullReference ? string.Empty : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Description);
            }
            set
            {
                Invoke(() => ComObject.Description = value);
            }
        }

        public bool Connect
        {
            get
            {
                return !IsWrappingNullReference && InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Connect);
            }
            set
            {
                Invoke(() => ComObject.Connect = value);
            }
        }

        public object Object // definitely leaks a COM object
        {
            get
            {
                return IsWrappingNullReference ? null : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Object);
            }
            set
            {
                Invoke(() => ComObject.Object = value);
            }
        }

        public override void Release()
        {
            if (!IsWrappingNullReference)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ComObject);
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.AddIn> other)
        {
            return IsEqualIfNull(other) || (other != null && other.ComObject.ProgId == ProgId && other.ComObject.Guid == Guid);
        }

        public bool Equals(AddIn other)
        {
            return Equals(other as SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.AddIn>);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return IsWrappingNullReference ? 0 : ComputeHashCode(ProgId, Guid);
        }
    }
}
```

The collection types implement `IEnumerable<WhateverTheWrapperTypeIs>` on top of that, and are responsible for releasing their children - e.g. here's the `AddIns` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Rubberduck.VBEditor.SafeComWrappers.VBA
{
    public class AddIns : SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Addins>, IEnumerable<AddIn>, IEquatable<AddIns>
    {
        public AddIns(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Addins comObject) : 
            base(comObject)
        {
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return IsWrappingNullReference ? 0 : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Count); }
        }

        public object Parent // todo: verify if this could be 'public Application Parent' instead
        {
            get { return IsWrappingNullReference ? null : InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Parent); }
        }

        public VBE VBE
        {
            get { return IsWrappingNullReference ? null : new VBE(InvokeResult(() => ComObject.VBE)); }
        }

        public AddIn Item(object index)
        {
            return new AddIn(InvokeResult(() => ComObject.Item(index)));
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            Invoke(() => ComObject.Update());
        }

        public override void Release()
        {
            if (!IsWrappingNullReference)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
                {
                    Item(i).Release();
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ComObject);
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Addins> other)
        {
            return IsEqualIfNull(other) || (other != null && ReferenceEquals(other.ComObject.Parent, Parent));
        }

        public bool Equals(AddIns other)
        {
            return Equals(other as SafeComWrapper<Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Addins>);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return IsWrappingNullReference ? 0 : ComputeHashCode(Parent);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return InvokeResult(() => ComObject.GetEnumerator());
        }

        IEnumerator<AddIn> IEnumerable<AddIn>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new ComWrapperEnumerator<AddIn>(ComObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This beauty seems to work perfectly.. but I don't like that I'm having to rely on `ComObject` in `GetHashCode` and `Equals` when I'm wrapping collection types and other types that don't really have any immutable data - because with COM interop, there's no guarantee that the returned hash code will be the same throughout the lifetime of the RCW... but I don't think I have any other options. Do I?

I don't like that I have an insignificant stack trace for whatever exception gets thrown in `Invoke` or `InvokeResult`, but I'm guessing that's the price to pay for lazy-accessing the underlying COM object.

Does anything else look wrong?

---

*By all means please correct me if I'm wrong here - this area of .net is shrouded in thick clouds, and the web keeps contradicting itself about it.

Comment: About the creation of rcw take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5771301/2655508

Comment: @Heslacher saw that, thanks; *Reference count is incremented each time the object is requested from within COM object* is actually what made me go and dispose/release everything (one COM object retrieved = one COM object released) - which led to the catastrophe depicted in the introduction of this post. An RCW *per object* makes sense.. but contradicts the examples in the post (accessing `VBE.ActiveVBProject` twice returns *the same object* twice, and therefore one RCW - releasing twice sends everything down in flames apparently.

Comment: That said, with *this* solution I now have a clean exit when the host document is closed before Rubberduck tears down, which is already a massive improvement.

Comment: Why do you catch different specific exceptions and then throw `new WrapperMethodException` for both? Does that exception have some knowledge of COMExceptions? Looks like really great code btw.

Comment: @RobH good question - I actually ended up outright removing that `WrapperMethodException` and the `Invoke`/`InvokeResult` methods too, since they really only existed so that I would be sure to `ThrowIfDisposed()`... but since I'm no longer implementing `IDisposable` it was all moot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public static bool operator ==(SafeComWrapper<T> a, SafeComWrapper<T> b)
> {
>     if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return !ReferenceEquals(a, null) && a.Equals(b);
> }
> ```

I think that this should be done a little differently, this looks overly complicated and a bit confusing.

I was thinking that a ternary statement would make this much cleaner and less redundant with the `ReferenceEquals(a, null)`

it would look something like this.

```
public static bool operator ==(SafeComWrapper<T> a, SafeComWrapper<T> b)
{
    return ReferenceEquals(a, null) ? ReferenceEquals(b, null) : a.Equals(b);
}
```